# undefined method "_index_path" form_for problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to generate a form using the form_for helper in RoR but I am encountering what seems to be a routing error. Here are the relevant files:

**models/equipment.rb**

```
class Equipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :tracking_number
  validates :tracking_number, :presence => true,
                              :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => true }
end
```

**controllers/equipments_controllers.rb**

```
class EquipmentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @equipments = Equipment.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @equipment  = Equipment.new
  end

end
```

**views/equipments/new.html.rb**

```
<h1>Add an equipment</h1>
<%= form_for (@equipment) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %> <br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tracking_number %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :tracking_number %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Add" %>
<% end  %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
EquipmentTracking::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "equipments#index"
  resources :equipments
end
```

I don't see anything wrong but they output the following:

```
NoMethodError in Equipments#new
Showing /opt/ror/equipment_tracking/app/views/equipments/new.html.erb where line #2 raised:
undefined method `equipment_index_path' for #<#<Class:0xb6725a2c>:0xb6724640>
```

If I changed it to

```
<%= form_for (:equipment) do |f| %>
```

it seems to work ok. I'm also certain that the static variable @equipment is getting passed since

```
<%= @equipment %>
```

returns

```
#<Equipment:0xb685ece0>
```

I am at a loss here. I just did what I did while I was following the railstutorial.org book and I was able to finish the book.

Comment: Is there any more content in those files?  equipment_index_path is rather peculiar and shouldn't be a routing path generated by Rails.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think your problem lies in your use of the word "equipments". If you open the Rails console run `'equipment'.pluralize`  you'll see that the plural of "equipment" is "equipment".

So I'd do a search through your project and replace any instance of "equipments" with "equipment" and I'd bet that would fix it.

Comment: Thanks! That did it. I should keep in mind to check the rails pluralize before making my controllers then.

Comment: I'd do better to check up on my vocabulary and my collective nouns too.