# RoR Error: undefined method students_index_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been getting this error and have been unable to fix it
(the post at StackOverflow [Undefined Method Index Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099915/undefined-method-index-path-form-for-problem) didn't fix my problem).
This exact error message I am getting is (I am using Rails 3.0.5 and Ruby 1.9.2):

```
NoMethodError in Students#new
```

Showing C:/rails/ww/app/views/students/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `students_index_path' for #<#:0x4991c10>

Here are the files:  
**students_controller.rb**

```
    class StudentsController < ApplicationController

      def new
         @students = Students.new
      end
    end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<h1>Enroll New Student</h1>
```

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', students_path %>

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@students) do |f| %>
  <% if @students .errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@students .errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this course from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @students .errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :pen %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :pen %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :fName %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :fName %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :lName %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :lName %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :pass %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :pass %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for the answer in advanced.

Comment: It looks like this is a route file issue. Make sure it is `resources :students` instead of `resources :student`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `<%= form_for(@student) do |f| %>` not `@students`

Answer (score 2):

Why your `model name is plural ?` It `should be singular.`
Just rename or drop/create your model with name `Student.`

Add `resources :students` to config/routes.rb

In controller, `@student = Student.new`

Thats it.. should work with this...

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are passing in the variable `@students` into `form_for`, so rails interprets that as `students_index_path`. If you were to pass in a variable named `@student`, you'd fine. (assuming you created a variable `@student = Student.new`)

I'd read up on how `form_for` interprets it's arguments [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for).

Answer (score 0):

Just add string in routes.rb

```
resources :students
```

instead

```
match "/students/:id" => "students#new"
```

or whatever you have (: