# undefined method on rails 3 scaffolded "new" action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes, nomethoderror

I was creating a scaffolded class on rails and then I tried to access it's "new" action but i got this error:

```
 NoMethodError in Medias#new

 Showing /Users/webcloud/Documents/Trabalhos/Reinaldo/Residencial/gerenciador/rails_estate/app/views/medias/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

 undefined method `media_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fbfdc371bf0>:0x007fbfdc36b6d8>
 Extracted source (around line #1):

 1: <%= form_for @media, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
 2:   <% if @media.errors.any? %>
 3:     <div id="error_explanation">
 4:       <h2><%= pluralize(@media.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this media from being  saved:</h2>
 Trace of template inclusion: app/views/medias/new.html.erb

 Rails.root: /Users/webcloud/Documents/Trabalhos/Reinaldo/Residencial/gerenciador/rails_estate

 Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
 app/views/medias/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_medias__form_html_erb___3954857503624418674_70230991238020'
 app/views/medias/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_medias_new_html_erb__3813674121976191732_70231004981260'
 app/controllers/medias_controller.rb:34:in `new'
```

the weird part is that it have the resource configured:

```
 resources :medias
```

And it's model is using the carrierwave gem to manage uploads

```
class Media < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gallery_data
  has_many :galleries, :through => :gallery_data
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  attr_accessible :file_name, :remote_image_url
  mount_uploader :file_name, ImageUploader
end
```

It's controller method (new) is just the same as any scaffolded method:

```
  # GET /media/new
  # GET /media/new.json
  def new
    @media = Media.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @media }
    end
  end
```

I don't really know what's going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099915/undefined-method-index-path-form-for-problem) for your solution.

To summarize, 'media' is pluralized 'media', not 'medias' as you have put.

```
$ rails console
> 'media'.pluralize
 => "media"
```

You'll need to change your `routes.rb` (and maybe some other code such as controller class names) in order to correct the problem.

Comment: Which is one reason, I've never approved of the Rails convention of using plurals for table names and controller names. I think it's possible to change that, but of course, when in Railsville, it's better to do as the Railsvilleites do, even in the cases where they happen to be "wrong". <g>

Comment: "Convention over configuration" is the stance I believe. I like it, it makes sense to me and I've never had to fight against it. Over anything else, it's nice to have the consistency. (Plus, "medias" isn't a word. Media *is* its own plural so this particular problem shouldn't come up too often.)

Comment: when I change the route to :media it translates wrong into:
new_medium GET    /media/new(.:format)

Comment: Not to go on for ever about this (and I do agree with "convention over configuration"), but to me, pluralizing in code is simply a bad choice of convention that leads to confusion and unnecessary internal complexity in the code base -- plus, in almost every other domain, singular table names are the norm. It helps to think of a table as a class of row. Anyway, that's just my minor Rails grumble for the day.

Comment: Like the answer linked for @Alex I switched to :media and solved my problem cause I could not solve the problem with the solution presented. I don't know if it is the best solution but it worked.

Comment: Well, but it don't solve my problem completely cause the path that the form uses is the "/medias/new" via POST and that is the wrong path according to the routes.rb

Comment: It's really a matter of the wrong name but I could not fix with the @Alex answer. But it did helped me to solve it.

Comment: I've followed this and completely solve the same error: http://blog.thefrontiergroup.com.au/2011/06/pluralizations-and-singularizations-inflections-in-rails-3/