# Undefined method with "_path" while using rails form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm running into a (I think) routing error while using the Rails form_for helper. I have been searching around and looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099915/undefined-method-index-path-form-for-problem), but the plural for "static_event" with pluralize is "static_events" so I am at a loss. Any help would be apprecited. Here are the details....

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `static_events_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f9fcc48a918>:0x007f9fcc46fa78>):
```

**My Model:**

```
class StaticEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :content, :title, :discount, :location, :day_of_week, :start_time
```

**My Controller:**

```
    class StaticEventsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:create, :destroy]
  before_filter :authorized_user, :only => [:destroy] 


  def new
    @title = "Share An Event"
    @static_event = StaticEvent.new 
  end

  def create
    @static_event = current_user.static_events.build(params[:event])
    if @static_event.save
      flash[:success] = "Event Shared"
      redirect_to @static_event #this was the old version
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

**The route:**

```
match '/static-events/new', :to => 'static_events#new'
match '/static-events/',     :to => 'static_events#index'
match '/static-events/:id', :to => 'static_events#show'
```

**The view**

```
<%= form_for (@static_event) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
<%= text_field "static_event", "title", "size" => 48 %>
<%= time_select "static_event", "start_time", {:ampm => true, :minute_step => 15} %>
<%= text_area "static_event", "content", "cols" => 42, "rows" => 5 %>
<%= text_field "static_event", "discount", "size" => 48 %>
<%= text_field "static_event", "location", "size" => 48 %>
<%= text_field "static_event", "day_of_week", "size" => 48 %>
<input name="" type="submit" class="button" value="share on chalkboard" />
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Only routes created using the `resources` method are automatically named.

If you want to name your routes, use the `:as` option:

```
match '/static-events/new', :to => 'static_events#new', :as => :new_static_event
match '/static-events/',     :to => 'static_events#index', :as => :static_events
match '/static-events/:id', :to => 'static_events#show', :as => :static_event
```

However, it's better to use the `resources` method. You must pass the "true" name of your model as the first parameter, then override the path if you want:

```
resources :static_events, :path => 'static-events'
```

Comment: In rails 4, you'll need to specify the http method as well with `via`

Comment: As a side not, for nested routes you'll have to pass a pair of values so `form_for ([@static_event,@sub_event])`

Comment: In Rails5; add ```resources :static_events``` to routes.rb

Answer (score 9):

First of all, you should define your routes this way:

```
resources 'static-events', :only => [:new, :create]
```

This will create a route for new and create methods.

Because when you use a new ActiveRecord object as an argument to form for, it will looks for *s_path like static_events_path in your routes file with the POST verb.

I think the way you have defined your routes doesn't create the static_events_path with POST verb (you can check that by using rake routes as megas said). So don't use match anymore, use resources or get/post/... instead of match in your Rails 3 projects.

**EDIT**

I did not notice yesterday, but there is no route for create method. Add the route below before **static_events#index** or remove all your routes and do like I said above.

```
post '/static-events/', :to => 'static_events#create'
```

Comment: `:static-events` is not a valid symbol

Comment: You're right injekt, symbols cannot contain dashes. I fixed the mistake

Answer (score 6):

Run `rake routes` and you'll see the list of your routes. Then you can fix the route file to have appropriate route path.

Comment: From what I can see, my routes look accurate.

Comment: Good debugging tip - this helped me.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me when i was using a nested resource, but forgot to actually initialize the parent resource using `load_and_authorize_resource` in cancan.  Therefore, the parent resource was null and it threw this error.

I fixed it by declaring `load_and_authorize_resource` on the parent in the controller.