# Custom model not working in rails 3.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am a newbie in ROR, so please help me with this.
I created a model named 'Customer' from rails console, in the database there is a table named 'Customers' and it has columns: id, name, address, gender, dob, credit_card, created_at and updated_at. So, to save these information I created a view such as:

```
<%= form_for(@customer) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :dob %><br />
<%= f.date_select :dob %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :gender %><br />
<%= f.text_field :gender %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :address %><br />
<%= f.text_field :address %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :phone_number %><br />
<%= f.text_field :phone_number %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :credit_card %><br />
<%= f.text_field :credit_card %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit 'Order', :action => :save_order  %>
</div>
```

this view would be called by 'public' controller, from action 'check_out'
the code for action check_out is as:

```
def check_out
  @customer = Customer.new
end
```

and code for action 'save_order' would be:

```
def save_order
   @customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])
   if @customer.save
      #somcode
   end
end
```

but i am getting a problem in the view part, "undefined method `customers_path' for #<#:0x9f49814>" in the line which contains "form_for(@customer)"
what i am doing wrong ? I am using rails 3.2.2
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706774/undefined-method-with-path-while-using-rails-form-for

Answer (score 0):

You don't have route for customer controller actions. Just add this line to `routes.rb` file

```
resources :customers
```

This one will generate several helpers, one of them will be `customers_path`. You can list all path helpers by command

```
rake routes
```

Comment: I dont have controller 'customers', I was hoping to use controller 'public' to create new customers.

Comment: Accordingly to MVC pattern it's better to have customers controller. Do not reinvent the wheel.