# Rails routes issue, undefined '******_path' with form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, namespaces, routes, match

So, I'm new to rails, and I'm building an app that will need to be versioned. My question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706774/undefined-method-with-path-while-using-rails-form-for), however, trying the given solutions to that have not resolved my issue.

Here's the error I get:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `questions_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000057bd2c0>:0x000000057b00e8>)
```

here is my view:

```
<h1>Create Question </h1>
<%= form_for(@question) do |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :text %>
    <%= f.text_field :text %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

here is my controller:

```
class Api::V1::QuestionsController < Api::V1::ApiController
  inherit_resources

  load_and_authorize_resource :user
  load_and_authorize_resource :through => :user

  def index
    respond_with @questions.unanswered(current_user)
  end

  def new
    @question = Question.new
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.new(params[:question])
    if @question.save
      #render :action => 'new'
    else
      puts @question.text
      puts @question.level
      puts @question.answers.inspect
    end
  end

#other methods...
end
```

and finally, the current version of my routes:

```
  namespace :api, :defaults => { :format => 'json' } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users do
        resources :questions, :path => 'questions' do
          collection do
            #get 'new', :to => 'questions#new', :as => :new_api_v1_user_question_path
          end
    end
      end

      resources :questions, :path => 'questions' do
        resources :answers do
          resources :responses
        end
        collection do
          #get 'new', :to => 'questions#new', :as => :new_api_v1_question_path
        end
      end
    end
  end

  match 'api/v1/user/:user_id/questions/new.html', :to => 'api/v1/user/:user_id/questions#new', :as => :new_api_v1_user_question
```

Basically, I don't know how to do the solution from [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706774/undefined-method-with-path-while-using-rails-form-for) with the namespace stuff I'm doing. As you can see, I've tried using match, I've commented out where I tried using resources and 'collection,' but no dice. I've mixed and matched all kinds of things, and either it gives me the error I've described here, or a "route doesn't exist" error. I've even looked at the [rails guides on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), but to no avail. Struggled with it for days. Please help!

Comment: try: `form_for([:api, :v1, @question])`

Comment: You can get routes, if run "rake routes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually figured this out. In my view, I had to make the form_for method call look like this:

```
<%= form_for(@question, :url => api_v1_questions_path ) do |f| %>
```

This fixed my problem.