# No method error in posts#edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am learning Rails following a udemy tutorial. Everything was good until this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbw1M.png), I keep rewinding the video and watched it over and over following the exact steps but somehow I always end up with this error.

Please help me the udemy forum as that course is not active at all so I am frustrated.

[this my view page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnvZq.png), this page is really weird with all these rules

Comment: its not letting me post more than 1 pictures :/

Comment: show us your routes.rb and posts_controller.rb

Comment: Yea, can you run `rake routes` in your console and let us know the output? These methods are generated from your routes.

Comment: it gives me a name error. I am trying to post the pictures it's not letting me :/

Comment: Then copy text of the error and not image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706774/undefined-method-with-path-while-using-rails-form-for Your case is defined here

Comment: can you please also add your controller file?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this..

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your error image, it's clear that your error is not in your view, the `form_for` tag calls some methods on the resource passed in, here it is `@post`. Make sure that @post is not nil.

Make sure your edit method is like this in your post_controller.rb:

```
 def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 end
```

Comment: i do have that exact code inside my controller under edit