# no method error in posts#edit (take 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I posted a question before but my pictures weren't posting so now I am just gonna copy and paste the code. I am trying to make a blogging web app is Rails and I am in the "edit" phase and basically I am getting a no method error.

here is my controller code:
 class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @post = Post.all
    end

```
def new
    @post = Post.new
end

def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save
    redirect_to show_path(@post)
end

def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

private

def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
end
```

end

and here is my edit.html.erb view page

## This is the edit page for

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
<%= f.label :title %>
<%= f.text_field :title %><br />

<%= f.label :body %>:
<%= f.text_field :body %><br />
```

I am guessing the problem is somewhere in there

here is my routes.rb:

Rails.application.routes.draw do

```
get "pages/about" => "pages#about"
get "pages/contact" => "pages#contact"

get "/posts" => "posts#index"

post "/posts" => "posts#create"

get "post/:id" => "posts#show", as: :show

get "/posts/new" => "posts#new"

get "post/:id/edit" => "posts#edit", as: :edit_post
```

end

Please help this is really frustrating :/

Comment: I wish I could post a picture of the error but it doesn't let me :/

Comment: Why you are not using `resources :posts` in your routes?

Comment: oh I am following this tutorial and he is not there or he didn't show us to do that. Should I be using it?

Comment: here is the error message:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a line in your route file such as:

```
resources :posts
```

Also add a update method in your posts_controller:

```
 def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.update(post_params)
    redirect_to @post
  end
```

I hope this helps you !

Answer (score 0):

When you use form_for like

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
```

It's a shorthand for something that looks like this

```
<%= form_for @post, as: :post, url: post_path(@post), method: :patch, html: { class: "edit_post", id: "edit_post_45" } do |f| %>
```

So form_for expects that you have defined post_path helper, which you get when you use resources to define your routes, like this

```
resources :photos
```

Since you haven't defined your routes like that you don't have path helper that form_for expects and you get an error.

Comment: So I should use resources :posts in the routes.rb? but I think I did that and the rails server stopped working :/

Comment: I suggest you that you read answer here, this is same case as yours
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706774/undefined-method-with-path-while-using-rails-form-for . I doubt that your server stopped because routes defined with resources.

Answer (score 0):

here is the error message:
NoMethodError in Posts#edit
Showing /Users/Hisham/Desktop/Rails_projects/myblog/app/views/posts/edit.html.erb where line #6 raised:

undefined method `post_path' for #<#:0x007fcdc84fd7b8>
Did you mean?  posts_path
               posts_new_path
               font_path
Extracted source (around line #6):
4
5
6
7
8
9

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
<%= f.label :title %>
<%= f.text_field :title %><br />
```

Rails.root: /Users/Hisham/Desktop/Rails_projects/myblog

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/posts/edit.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_posts_edit_html_erb___871381459853082993_70260921890920'