# I am getting this error: NoMethodError at ... undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, nomethoderror

I am a newbie on rails. I am building an app with Users, Restaurants, and Reservations. Everything was fine until I added the reservations and associations.

I am using nested resources for reservations and restaurants. My routes file has this.

```
resources :restaurants do
  resources :reservations
end
```

I added a reservations link on my restaurant view to link to **new_restaurant_reservation**. When I click on that link, it gives me this error:

```
NoMethodError at /restaurants/14/reservations/new
undefined method `reservations_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fc50d96ba98>:0x007fc51001a518>
Did you mean?  resolve_asset_path
```

Please help and let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to change reservations_path to restaurant_reservations_path, the problem is in the name of the route, I believe.  This should be in the reservations/new.html.erb

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706774/undefined-method-with-path-while-using-rails-form-for), it seems to be very similar to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'path' to the end of your link and the id of the resturaraunt. Something along the lines of

```
new_restaurant_reservation_path(:restuarant_id)
```

Comment: Thanks. This was very helpful.