# form_for not working for Acta model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models: `User`, and `Acta`, two controllers: `UsersController` and `ActasController`, etc.

The following works in a template:

```
<%= form_for User.new do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

while the following fails:

```
<%= form_for Acta.new do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

The error shown is:

```
Showing /Users/gdiazc/workspace-rails/rev_dem/app/views/actas/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:
undefined method `acta_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fc4a609b678>:0x007fc4a74026a8>
```

I suspect this might have something to do with pluralization, as `acta_index_path` sounds strangely pluralized. I then added the following code to `config/environment.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'acta', 'actas'
end
```

With no change. Any help? (Rails 4.1.4)

Comment: What's in your routes?

Comment: I have ``resources :users``, and ``resources :actas`` included.

Comment: That's bizarre as that wouldn't give a named route of `acta_index_path`

Comment: I completely agree! I have been a while staring at it...

Comment: Can you include your `rake routes`

Comment: After trying @Panczo's suggestion in the console I see that ``"acta".pluralize`` gives ``acta``, which is wrong. I re-added the inlfect override (see above) and ran ``db:reset`` + ``db:migrate``. My problem now is that the table is called ``acta`` and not ``actas``!

Comment: The issue has been fixed. It was not enough to run ``db:reset``. I had to erase the ``development.sqlite3`` file. Moral of the story: check pluralizations of your model before you even run the migration!

Answer (score 1):

I think the same problem is here [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099915/undefined-method-index-path-form-for-problem)

I try in console 'acta'.pluralize => 'acta'